# git pull and file permissions

Tags: linux, git

I am trying to pull a change from a git repo using git pull but I am getting this error:

```
error: unable to unlink old 'folder/file.php' (Permission denied)
```

the permissions are 664 for file.php and owner:group are my user.  So I changed the permissions to 775 thinking I just needed write access, but now when I do a git pull I get an error saying I need to stash my local changes.  How can I pull the changes for this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To unlink a filename, you need `w` and `x` on the directory that contains it.

Undo that silly 775 and look at the directory permissions.

```
ls -ld folder
```